# Access User's Text In a Textbox

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

I've set up an HTML webpage with a text field, a button, and an empty paragraph. Ideally, when the user presses the button, the text they've entered into the text field gets added to the empty paragraph on the page. I know that text can be added to the paragraph using this javascript line:

```
document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML="text";
```

But how do I access the text that the user typed into the text field so that I can use that text in the javascript line?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('id.of.input.here').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<input type='text' id='textBox' />

<script>
    document.getElementById("textBox").value="text";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it :

```
document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = document.getElementById("textBox").value;
```

Where `textBox` is the `id` of the text field.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type = "button" value = "Click" onclick="document.getElementById('paragraphId').value+=document.getElementById('textfieldId').value;">
```

Comment: Can you please expand your answer.

Comment: i edited the answer. Just change the paragraph id and the textfield id. and put the "onclick" function on your own button.